# Why does tensorflow doubles the one_hot on values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I have the following test program in Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Some tensor we want to print the value of
a = tf.one_hot(1,5)

# Add print operation
a = tf.Print(a, [a], message = "This is a: ")

# Add more elements of the graph using a
b = tf.add(a, a)

b.eval()
```

I call the function that shall create a nice one hot encoding. I would expect that the output is:

```
array([0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

But instead the output is:

```
array([0., 2., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

Why?

Comment: Why would you expect that output? `a` is the value `1` one-hot-encoded in five features, so `[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]` (since data type is `tf.float32` by default), then `b` is twice that tensor, hence the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `a` to itself, and then printing the addition. So essentially... `a= 1; print (a+a)`
Obviously, that's not how it's written, but I sure hope that 1+1 is 2.

Comment: Oh. Ups. I searched a tutotial about printing tensors, coppied it and filled in the call of one_hot. Obviously add does an addition.
So if i just call a.eval() everything is like expected.